# What format are the timestamps returned by the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn's API returns the following value:

```
[creationTimestamp] => 1407247548000
```

It looks similar to a UNIX timestamp, but there are three "extra" zeros at the end.  What format is this in, and how can I decode it?

Comment: Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch) from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Nope - its got too many numbers.

Comment: What does their (meaning linkedin) documentation state?

Comment: My query was because I have not come across a timestamp in milliseconds before only seconds.

Comment: Also used by Java, which is more likely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a timestamp in milliseconds.  Handling this is language dependent.  Some languages may expect a timestamp in milliseconds, while others may expect it in seconds.  Python 3, for example, expects seconds, but also handles microseconds (1000 milliseconds).

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = 1407247548124
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts / 1000)
print(dt)  # datetime(2014, 8, 5, 14, 5, 48, 124000)
```

Python 2 doesn't handle milliseconds directly (it ignores the fractional part), so you need to split the milliseconds out separately.

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = 14072475481234
secs, millis = divmod(ts, 1000)
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(secs).replace(microsecond=millis * 1000)
print(dt)  # datetime(2014, 8, 5, 14, 5, 48, 124000)
```